# Order of execution for PostgreSQL when UNION and INTERSECT are used

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, union, intersect

I am trying to build a query string that involves the use of multiple UNION and INTERSECT clauses on PostgresSQL/google-BigQuery. I want to understand the order in which each of the select statements will get executed in the following case.

```
A UNION B INTERSECT C UNION D
```

1. 

> (((A UNION B) INTERSECT C) UNION D)

2. 

> (A UNION (B INTERSECT (C UNION D)))

Will it be right-to-left or left-to-right or something different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left to right but `INTERSECT` binds more tightly than `UNION`:

```
(A UNION (B INTERSECT C)) UNION D
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-union.html